# Wordpress remove action declared in parent theme in hook function

Tags: php, wordpress, parent-child

My parent theme prints inline styles in header. One I want to remove.
Inside *controls.php* in ***public function hook()***:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', array($this, 'display_customization') );
```

This function looks like this:

```
public function display_customization()
    {
        do_action('zoom_customizer_display_customization_css', $this->get_css_rules());

        $css = zoom_customizer_get_css()->build();

        if (!empty($css)) {
            echo "\n<!-- Begin Theme Custom CSS -->\n<style type=\"text/css\" id=\"" . WPZOOM::$theme_raw_name . "-custom-css\">\n";
            echo $css;
            echo "\n</style>\n<!-- End Theme Custom CSS -->\n";
        }
    }
```

It adds inline style with id="foodica-pro-custom-css"

I tried

```
remove_action( 'wp_head','display_customization', 120);
```

and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

#### The main issue above is that the action is added using the class method callback syntax

`array($this, 'display_customization')` so you can't remove it using directly the function name

#### https://gist.github.com/tripflex/c6518efc1753cf2392559866b4bd1a53

Here you can find an implementation of `remove_class_action` and `remove_class_filter` that allow you to remove actions and filters that have been created using the class syntax.

Once you have the above code in your project using the following syntax:

`remove_class_action('wp_head', 'NameOfClassThatThisRefersToInControlsFile', 'display_customization');`

#### Some other things to note:

`remove_action` and `remove_class_action` from above need to have the same signature as add action, so please keep the priority the same. If the add call has no priority as above (so it has the default priority of 10), please keep the remove call the same.

Another issue that you could encounter here is to make sure the remove_action or remove_class_action calls are in fact called after the add_action.

Depending on where the add_action is called, you might have to put your remove call inside a specific hook, to make sure the remove call is executed after the add call.